# article url format for google news sitemap

Tags: sitemap, url

I have 2 questions about url for google news sitemap.

1. Is it good that I use= url for sitemap witch like `http://www.mydomain.com/news?query=football&title=Poland-coach-Smuda-names-Euro-2012-squad`, the page is a search results include the article `Poland coach Smuda names Euro 2012 squad` and 10 search result with keyword `football`? Or I should do an independent page only one article and url like `http://www.mydomain.com/news-article/Poland-coach-Smuda-names-Euro-2012-squad`?
2. Could I do some url like `http://www.mydomain.com/news#!Poland-coach-Smuda-names-Euro-2012-squad` which url rule under AJAX hash crawling from [google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2009/10/proposal-for-making-ajax-crawlable.html) for the sitemap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documented requirements](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#locdef) for the `loc` element are:

> This URL must begin with the protocol (such as http) and end with a trailing slash, if your web server requires it. This value must be less than 2,048 characters.

As long as your URLs resolve, they should be fine. Neither is "good" *or* bad; the issue is whether they're valid. Yes to both.

Note this is completely independent of any opinions on SEO-type details like whether query or Ajax-style URLs are better, etc., which fall outside of your actual question.

Comment: thanx, +1, waiting for more suggestion.